# Editing view perspective

Tags: feature-request, documentation

In documentation while in Editing mode the editor window comes down and generally splits the screen horizontally in two. This wastes quite a lot of screen space.

If the Editor was split vertically, or had a option to move to the right, then it would be much easier to edit, also one would be easily able to compare changes simultaneously. All the more for bigger screens this would be much better, which can easily encompass the width of Post on half a screen.

What say?